# login after ubuntu 11.10 upgrade - failed to load session ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, gdm, ubuntu-11.10

After Ubuntu 11.10 upgrade I'm unable to login via gdm or lightdm.

Every time I receive error: `"failed to load session ubuntu"`

Any help appreciated.